# HTML onsubmit Event Attribute not triggering email to send

Tags: php, html, email, events

So the problem is as follows...

I have a `email.php` file with a working email that send out a confirmation.
I also have a file called `booking.php` which contains the form for booking an appointment. The form has an `action="treatment_form"` event which updates all the values to a Database in mySQL. That form has a `value="submit"` in the `<input>` field.

I have added a `onsubmit="email.php"` to the `<form>`, the data updates to the database, but the email never actually sends.

Here is my html code:

```
<form action="treatment_form.php" onsubmit="email.php" method="post"> 
    <div class="heading1">
        <p>Select Your Treatment:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <select name="Treatment"><?php echo $options; ?></select>
    </div>

    <div class="heading4">
        <p>Add a message for our Staff:</p>
        <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Enter Message..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Request Booking" id="Submit">
        </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**
`treatment_form.php`:

```
$hostname = '#';
$dbname = '#';
$username = '#';
$password = '#';

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$insert = "INSERT INTO Booking_request_form (treatment, date, time, message, client_fk) VALUES('".$_POST["Treatment"]."', '".date('m/d/Y',strtotime($_POST["Date"]))."', '".date('H:i',strtotime($_POST["Time"]))."', '".$_POST["Message"]."', '".$_SESSION['id_client']."')";


//var_dump($insert);
$handle = mysql_query($insert);
//var_dump($handle);

?>
```

Comment: onsubmit should be JS function instead of php file name.

Comment: Do you know how I can write a JS function to trigger `email.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is using
`email.php`
in the `onsubmit` function. It is supposed to specify a function to be performed on the submission in the form, preferably by JavaScript.

You can try merging email.php with treatment_form.php, with which, the email is sent once the query is complete and successful.

Like this:
treatment_form.php

```
if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){ include('email.php');}
```

As an alternative you can also use onsubmit to trigger a JavaScript function to run email.php on the background, maybe with ajax.

If you need to check out a PHP Ajax tutorial it's right here-
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

**Update**

```
//After the line where you have completed the query successfully
if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)) { include('email.php'); //make sure you have all the variables you need for email.php is ready}
mysqli_close($con); //close the connection
```

**NOTE:**
`mysql_*` 
 functions have been deprecated and removed in PHP 7. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Do you mean adding that bit of code to `treatment_form.php`?

Comment: Yep, once you've made the query, check if it is successful, if it is- then simple include email.php with the given variables.

Comment: Ahh, I am not too sure how to do that... :(

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer and show us your treatment.php, I can show where to put it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106102/discussion-between-filip-and-coder-dude-twodee).

Answer (score 0):

your code is quite ambiguous in the following way ->

action attribute decides which page to go and onsubmit is an event attribute which decides which script to run on submitting the form .
 You are supposed to run a script (javascript) with the help of onsubmit event .

try to use ajax with php click to [know more](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp)

P.S. i am not a native english speaker